# Difference between "wegfahren", "fortfahren", "losfahren" and "abfahren"

Tags: difference, verb, synonym, comparison

*Wegfahren*, *fortfahren*, *losfahren*, *abfahren* — all these verbs mean *to leave* by car (e.g. *drive away*, *drive off*). But is there any difference between them or are they complete synonyms? In case of difference, please, provide an example.

As far as I know, there are [other verbs](http://en.pons.com/translate?q=leave&l=deen&in=&lf=de&kbd=de) in German to describe the leaving place action, such as *abreisen* and *verreisen*, but in the specific question I'm curious to understand the difference between all kind of **fahren* verbs.

Comment: Not only by car. *Ich fahre auch **mit dem Fahrrad** weg* or *… los*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Wegfahren*** (drive off) is focussing on a short movement from a given location without concern for a final destination, although this movement might as well be only the beginning of a longer journey. The means of transport is usually a private one, a car, motorcycle, bicycle, etc.:

> Fahr von dort weg, du stehst im Halteverbot.
>
> Ich fahre noch kurz weg.
>
> Wir wollten über Ostern wegfahren, doch leider bekam ich keinen Urlaub.
>
> Als sie wegfuhr, wusste sie nicht, ob sie jemals zurückkehren würde.

The meaning of ***fortfahren*** (drive away) is close to that of "wegfahren" but implies a longer journey or absence. It is more often about driving away from home than from a temporary accomodation:

> Ich fahre morgen fort, und ob wir uns wiedersehen, ist ungewiss.

But it can as well mean *to continue* (for this, see the answers to [that question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22522/differences-between-fortfahren-fortsetzen-weitermachen-weitergehen-an))

***Losfahren*** simply means starting to move, to get under way, usually with a private means of transport:

> Wann fahren wir endlich los?
>
> Als sie losfuhren, brach ein schweres Unwetter herein.

It can also refer to a public vehicle, or any vehicle when the driver is not important in the sentence, but in this case the vehicle itself is the subject:

> Als das Auto losfuhr, bemerkten sie, dass die Heckklappe noch offen war.
>
> Der Bus fuhr sofort los, als alles Gepäck verstaut war.
>
> Der Zug fuhr langsam los, als das Signal die Fahrt freigab.

...although for a train, "anfahren" (start) is more common.

***Abfahren*** means taking off, usually on regular public service like train or bus.

> Wann fährt dieser Zug endlich ab?

***Abreisen*** (depart) usually signifies the end of a temporary stay at a certain location, departing by all proper means of transport for a longer journey.